# How to add 13min's time in Time Field(not date time field) Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

I tried using `Dateadd('n',13,{fieldname})`.

but it throws an error not a valid date time field cause it is time field.
is there any way to convert it to datetime and add the value and revert it into time field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

`DateAdd('n',13,DateTime(CurrentDate, {fieldname}))`

The `DateTime(date, time)` function will create a DateTime value that works in the `DateAdd()` function.  This will only work if the `{fieldname}` is a Time data type though.

If `{fieldname}` is a string, you will need to convert it to a Time data type first using the `Time(time)` function.

The formula I suggested above will append your time value to today's date.  You will then need to format the DateTime value it returns to only display the time value.  This can be done by right clicking the field in your crystal report and clicking Format Field and setting the Style on the Date and Time tab.

Comment: Works Perfect!! thanks, Is there a way to convert it  back into string for ex: i changed the format to 6:00 or 5:69 to 600 or 569.

Comment: To convert it to a string you would use the `ToText()` function or the `CStr()` function.  Both can accept 2 arguments to provide formatting options.  ie...  `ToText({DateTimeField} , "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" )` or `CStr({DateTimeField} , "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" )`.  Both functions work the same, but are supported differently in Crystal Syntax vs Basic Syntax.